# RxJava- No access to Observable's subscribers?

Tags: java, monads, reactive-programming, rx-java

I learned [it is undesirable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1794) to use `Subjects` in reactive programming although I found them highly convenient. But I understand they can be abused. So I tried to create an infinite `Observable<ImmutableMap<Integer,ActionProfile>` that needs to publish a new `ImmutableMap`every time `refresh()` is called. I also have a `forKey()` method that returns an `Observable` retrieving the latest `ActionProfile` matching a specific key.

However, something just doesn't feel kosher with how I'm handling the subscribers. Am I correct that you have to manage the subscribers yourself outside the Observable's construction if the Observable's life is infinite? Does the Observable maintain a list of its subscribers? Or is that onus on me so I can call their `onNext()` at any time?

```
public final class ActionProfileManager {
    private final Observable<ImmutableMap<Integer,ActionProfile>> actionProfiles;
    private volatile ImmutableMap<Integer,ActionProfile> actionProfileMap;

    //do I really need this?
    private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscriber<? super ImmutableMap<Integer,ActionProfile>>> subscribers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private ActionProfileManager() {
        this.actionProfiles = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            subscriber.onNext(actionProfileMap);
            subscribers.add(subscriber); // is it up to me to capture the subscriber here or is it already saved somewhere for me?
        });
    }

    public void refresh() { 
        actionProfileMap = importFromDb();
        subscribers.forEach(s -> s.onNext(actionProfileMap));
    }

    public Observable<ActionProfile> forKey(int actionProfileId) { 
        return actionProfiles.map(m -> m.get(actionProfileId));
    } 
    private ImmutableMap<Integer,ActionProfile> importFromDb() { 
        return ImmutableMap.of(); //import data here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not experienced enough to give a competent answer to your question, but: 1.) You may find this answer to my question on CR interesting: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90090/68342 2.) You may want to look at the source code sqlbrite, particularly this file which uses a `Subject` internally to handle reloads/triggers: https://github.com/square/sqlbrite/blob/master/sqlbrite/src/main/java/com/squareup/sqlbrite/SqlBrite.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cold Observables generally interact with a single Subscriber at a time and even if you subscribe more to them, they run independently and don't really need to know about each other.

Subjects, on the other hand, have to track their subscribers as they multicast events they themselves receive.

A quick look at your code indicates there are a few race conditions and possibility of lost notifications. Instead of it, you could rely on `BehaviorSubject` which is the 'reactive property' of the async word. Let it store the current immutable map and handle the subscribers:

```
BehaviorSubject<ImmutableMap> bs = BehaviorSubject.create();
Subject<ImmutableMap, ImmutableMap> sync = bs.toSerialized();

forKey(k): bs.map(m -> m.get(k));

refresh(): sync.onNext(importFromDb());
```

Comment: I suspected the possibility of race conditions. So why do folks often say subjects should almost never be used? For my purposes and by what you've shown, they seem to be appropriate in some cases.

Comment: Such "don't use" statements felt always to harsh to me. I'd say you should first look for other ways first, but there are certain usage expectancies that imply the use of Subject almost immediately.